# TabPage as userControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I want to create  tabpage as userControl.

Is there any way to deal with this??

Comment: because, a I have a simillar tabcontrol  with one paramter which is type, and there is no sense , to copy that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a TabPage, and add a UserControl to it...

```
TabControl tabControl1 = new TabControl();
TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Tab");
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
tp.Controls.Add(new MyUserControl());
```

Comment: I like this solution, but the original version didn't compile, so I fixed it.